# How to call action after animation rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an animation that I want to happen before an action is called.

The animation is triggered via a div's onclick command.

what i would like is for a js animation to be called resulting in a rails action being called and afterwards redirecting to a success page.

I am using Rails 3 and jQuery as my js library. I would like it to be done in such a way that if the computer running the site does not have JS enabled it will just preform the action and redirect to the success page.

Thanks, Muki.

ANYONE??

Comment: may be its me but you really need to re-phrase your question it's confusing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your answer: [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery)